# R Subset of pam, Arrange multiple figures in one

Tags: r, cluster-computing, pam

I'm struggling with the following problem:
I use `pam` to cluster my dataset `v` in 7 clusters:

```
x <- pam(v,7)
```

I know that there is a vector `clustering` in `x` which contains the according numbers of clusters.

I would like to get a subset of `x` which only contains cluster 1.

Is this possible?

Edit:
Here is an example. Cluster `iris` in three clusters and plot them.

```
library(ggfortify)
library(cluster)

v <- iris[-5]
x <- pam(v,3)
autoplot(x, frame = TRUE, frame.type = 'norm')
```

The question: How can I plot only the first cluster? It should look like the first plot without cluster 2 and 3.

Edit: I think I found a solution. Therefore I don't use autoplot anymore but calculate the convex hull of every cluster and plot it.

```
library(cluster)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

find_hull <- function(df) df[chull(df$x, df$y),]

v<-iris[-5]
pp <- pam(v,3)

n<-princomp(pp$data, scores = TRUE, cor = ncol(pp$data) != 2)$scores
df<-data.frame(n[,1],n[,2],pp$clustering)
colnames(df)<-c("x","y","z")

hulls <- ddply(df, "z", find_hull)

p<-qplot(x,y,data=df,color=as.factor(z))+
   geom_polygon(data=hulls, alpha=1, fill=NA)+
   geom_text_repel(aes(label = rownames(df)),arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.00, 'inches'), angle = 0.00),size=5.5,colour="grey55")+
   theme_classic(base_size = 16)+
   theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
    panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())
p

df2<-df[df$z==1,]
hulls <- ddply(df2, "z", find_hull)

p1<-qplot(x,y,data=df2,color=as.factor(z))+
    geom_polygon(data=hulls, alpha=0.8, fill=NA)+
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = rownames(df2)),arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.00, 'inches'), angle = 0.00),size=5.5,colour="grey25")+
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)+
      theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
    panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())+ 
p1
```

Now I want to plot both figures in one device. I have already tried the multiplot from [cookbook-r](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/) but it gives the error

```
 Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (26): label, x, y
```

It must be because of the labels I guess.

I also tried

```
grid.arrange(p,p1, ncol=1)
```

from the `gridExtra` package but it gives the same error. 
Is there any other option to arrange multiple figures with labels in one figure?

Comment: I guess it is possible, yes.

Comment: Sorry, library(ggfortify) is also needed.